# What does the term "hot dog lawyer" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the term "hot dog lawyer" mean? I've heard this term quite a few times, and I am not sure what does the term "hot dog" as an adjective describe?

For example:

> “And they usually don't have a hot-dog lawyer waiting for them when  they arrive at the station.”

From the book: ['Death by Sudoku' by Kaye Morgan](https://books.google.com/books?id=AcPZo3W2ovUC&pg=PT47&dq=%22hot-dog+lawyer+waiting+for+them+when+they+arrive%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHjcOKw5nbAhVEpFkKHXdFBDIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22hot-dog%20lawyer%20waiting%20for%20them%20when%20they%20arrive%22&f=false)

> Sally Yates is a hotdog lawyer who never should have been the acting attorney general.

[Joe diGenova, on Fox News](https://youtu.be/yAh0-tLwl5c?t=368) (with [transcript of video](http://www.foxnews.com/transcript/2018/05/15/giuliani-mueller-cant-indict-or-subpoena-president.html)).

> He was a hot-dog lawyer from Dallas with one of those seven-figure houses on Truman Annex.

From the novel ['Air Dance Iguana' by Tom Corcoran](https://books.google.com/books?id=fjthVtAKW4sC&pg=PA57&dq=%22hot-dog+lawyer+from+Dallas%22&hl=en&sa=X&q=%22hot-dog%20lawyer%20from%20Dallas%22#v=snippet&q=%22hot-dog%20lawyer%20from%20Dallas%22&f=false)

Comment: @BrianDonovan Yes, the intended meaning of 'hotdog' is the second entry. But the figurative meaning is so far from the connotations that it is very difficult (without understanding all the cultural implications) to choose the right one. Is that guy a 'show-off'? Maybe, so I can make the leap to connect to the word. But that leap may not be obvious to someone who doesn't share the culture (or the word).

Comment: I'm sure the phrase that you're hearing is "hotshot lawyer". Google Ngram offers no results for the alternative. As an aside, if you do ever grab a hotdog from one of those London street vendors, it might be an idea to have a lawyer nearby.

Comment: @Strawberry Not every useful pair of words has already been uttered. [It's not an atypical co-occurrence](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=%22atypical+collocation%22) like ['hamburger doctor'](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=%22hamburger+doctor%22) (those links are of course arguable). But there are lots of questionable hits for ['hot dog lawyer'](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=%22hot+dog+lawyer%22)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> hot-dog lawyer

(or 'hot dog' or 'hotdog', there's no difference here) is not a lawyer that eats hotdogs or represents hotdogs in court or is made of hotdog.

This is a very figurative use of the word 'hotdog'. Here it means [someone who shows off or is self-aggrandizing in an ostentatious manner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hotdog).

Of course, the first meaning of 'hot dog' as [a synonym for frankfurter-style sausage](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hot%20dog) (from ~1890), is not particularly literal already. Its origin is obscure, but probably a glib humorously intended coinage, possibly implying the source of the meat. In contemporary American usage, that connection is barely noticed. Puns involving it are rarely so literal and usually involve a dog on the beach rather than in a slaughterhouse.

In the end, there is nothing special about 'lawyer' here. You can have a hot dog fighter pilot, a hot dog wind surfer, a hot dog salesperson, anyone who could be said to be showing off their skills and maybe a little out of control.

Comment: I did not even consider looking at Merriam given, quite frankly, I thought "hot dog" is a type of food! But clear explanation, thank you

Comment: @LearnByReading "quite **frankly**"... ba-dum tss.

Comment: I can't shake the idea of a court made of hot-dog. I want 10 of them.

Comment: @PaulaHasstenteufel [What about pickles?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2dbe_PV5_E)

Comment: [An example of a hot dog lawyer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCWbe1YLJQ8)

Comment: @Learn - I can't be the only one smiling at the irony of how someone named "LearnByReading" "did not even consider" looking in a dictionary.

Comment: Did you check FumbleFingers first link for hot dog lawyer? Why do I read 640 results? Let's assume that Google Books' estimates are wildly optimistic and the results are far fewer, it would still be more than 10, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 21):

It's essentially an American usage, so perhaps as a Brit I shouldn't comment. But I found just 10 instances of [*hot dog lawyer*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hot%20dog%20lawyer%22) (and 4 instances of [*hotdog lawyer*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hotdog%20lawyer%22)) in Google Books.

Set against a claimed 6,590 instances of [***hotshot*** lawyer](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hotshot%20lawyer%22) (and 3040 of [***hot shot*** lawyer](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hot%20shot%20lawyer%22), which will also include those for hyphenated ***hot-shot***), I think the only reasonable conclusion is that a few people have misheard / incorrectly recalled the idiomatic standard usage here.

---

> **hotshot**, adjective  ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hotshot))
>   1: highly successful and aggressive:
>    *a hotshot lawyer; a hotshot account exec.*
>
> 2: displaying skill flamboyantly:
>    *a hotshot ballplayer.*

---

***Hot dog!*** is a colloquial AmE exclamation usually meaning something like ***Wow!, Great!, That's amazing!*** It has no significant currency as an adjective meaning ***high quality, very good.***

---

I should point out that ***hot[-]dog*** does have more extended use (derived from the original approving exclamation as mentioned above). From [Merriam-Webster...](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hotdog)

> *Surfers adopted it from the use of the noun **hot dog** for someone who is very good at something... In time, the noun became mainly associated with people who showed off their skills in sports, from basketball to skiing, and the verb form came to be used for the spectacular acts of these show-offs.*

But I think flamboyant lawyers only win in Hollywood movies. In real life I'd rather have a highly successful and aggressive lawyer batting for me - if I had the money, bearing in mind it's almost *proverbial* that most of us can't [afford a hotshot lawyer.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22afford%20a%20hotshot%20lawyer%22)

Comment: As an American, I must disagree with your "only reasonable conclusion".   *Hot-dog* is a valid modifier for lawyers and other professions (besides vendors).

Comment: A "hot-shot" is a rather complimentary;  "hot-dog" is rather derogatory.

Comment: -1 I don't believe I've ever heard Hot dog as an exclamation outside of a 1950's era TV show.  Definitely not a usage that is common in modern AmE.  Hot Dog Lawyer is perfectly valid in American English.

Comment: @Hellion: Like I said, I'm *not* an American, so maybe I'm mistaken here. But do you honestly think it's "reasonable" to just ignore a preference in written instances of almost 1000:1 in favour of ***hot[-]shot** lawyers?* Particularly given that *specific* collocation is the one chosen as a typical usage example by the dictionary I cited.

Comment: Perhaps it's **a** reasonable conclusion, but not **the only** reasonable conclusion?

Comment: @TobySpeight: It's just taken me a couple of minutes to end up with 1945 as the earliest written instance of [*hot-shot lawyers*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ours+had+hot-shot+lawyers+that+named%22). Which did surprise me a bit (I'd have thought it was *much* older), but all 10 of the instances of *hot dog lawyer* in my answer link are from the last decade. So maybe it *is* an "emerging usage" - but from my perspective it's *also* a "copying error".

Comment: Absolutely - I was just pointing out that your wording suggests that anyone with different opinions to you is unreasonable, and people tend to get defensive when you call them that.  Another reasonable conclusion could be that recent usage of "hot-dog lawyer" is completely intentional, and a few people have copied it.  (I have no opinion on which is correct, just that there's more than one plausible hypothesis).

Comment: @Toby: I now know all about hot dogging and surfing & such, and I've been familiar with the "exclamatory" usage since the 60s. But I just can't see why anyone would *deliberately* choose to change well-established ***hotshot*** to the unusual "niche patois" ***hot dog*** in this context. Besides which, surely they'd get fed up with people keep saying *I think you'll find that's "**hotshot** lawyer"*

Comment: ...but on reflection I think I should concede that at least *some* of the people who would be willing to refer to ***hot dog lawyers*** might be doing so in full awareness of how it might look to an "outsider" (such as myself! :) Whatever - I've hedged it as *...no **significant** currency*.

Comment: I'm Canadian. My mother, originally from the US, often uses the phrase *Hot dog!* in place of *Wow!*, so I'm use to hearing it used that way all the time around her. But, I have *never* heard the phrase "hot dog lawyer* until just now; in contrast, I'm very familiar with "hotshot lawyer." Although it seems plausible that a "hot dog lawyer" *now* means a "show off," it also seems plausible that it originated out of confusion, as you say. (Yet, looking at the expression, perhaps the two phrases developed in parallel.)

Comment: @JasonBassford: I'd love to find a reference to someone saying *He's just a hotdog lawyer!* with the contextually obvious implication *He's small-time / not much good. The kind of guy that could barely run a hotdog stand* (I bet any money things like that *have* been said, even if not so much today).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - when you say "copying error" I think the word you're looking for is [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It has enough currency to have been the call sign of a pilot on Battlestar Galactica.

Comment: @TKK: I'm sure "pet names" like that would be derived from *the **noun** "hot dog" for someone who is very good at something*, as popularised by surfers in the 60s. I just said it doesn't have any real currency as an ***adjective*** suitable for applying to *kick-ass / fancy / top-notch lawyers* and such.

Comment: What bothers me most about this answer is that it's saying "the only reasonable conclusion is that a few people have misheard / incorrectly recalled the idiomatic standard usage here." To hell with hit counts; the OP has quoted multiple usages of _hot dog lawyer_ verbatim. One phrase is not invalidated just because another is more common.

Comment: My mind *instantly* went to basketball (and presumably other American sports), where "hot dogging" means showing off. This is still a fairly common usage, definitely not dated. A "hot dog" player is someone who likes to show off. Perhaps the author of OP's passage is a sports fan who would naturally choose "hot dog" instead of "hot shot". And @J.R. you're absolutely right, but I suppose that's why the answerer did put the disclaimer that they're British. Of course they wouldn't know how Americans actually speak, and referencing books doesn't help with that :)

Comment: @sgroves - You may be onto something; one of those three authors is Tom Corcoran, who is (among other things) a screenwriter and an automotive magazine editor. The term _hot-dog driver_ probably wouldn't be unfamiliar to the author of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Mustang-1964-Restoration-Motorbooks-Workshop/dp/0760305528/ref=la_B001HCV6Q2_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1526590723).

Comment: @J.R. Ooh, nice find. I actually wouldn't be surprised if this sense of "hot dogging" originated in car racing, but I'm unsure of the origin.

Comment: I must be the only one who ever bothers clicking on links... where did you get the 10 hits from? If I click on the link, and just stop on the first page, Google Books reports 640 results. If I click on page 10 it estimates [625 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hot+dog+lawyer%22&num=20&tbm=bks&ei=2k4EW4X2Aoui0gLRhpigCQ&start=180&sa=N&biw=1316&bih=619&dpr=1.1) and if I click on page 11 the results disappear. I am growing increasingly disenchanted with Google Books's estimates. Still... I'd like to know why you listed only ten results for "hot dog lawyer"

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: I can't explain what's going on there. When I did that first Google Books search last week, it definitely claimed just 10 hits (within which I'm fairly sure I could only see the actual words *in context* in 2 or 3 cases). Now it says there are 618 hits, but context is only visible for the first 2 (I only checked the first half-dozen pages, but obviously there weren't going to be any more "real" hits). The figure for ***hotshot lawyer*** is still about the same, but ***hot-shot lawyer*** has suddenly gone up from 3040 to 3430 hits. It's weird, but that doesn't invalidate my point.

Comment: I think it does though, your answer hints that "hot dog lawyer" is (or was) an acorn or mondegreen for "hotshot lawyer" and you use Google Books statistics to firmly support your theory.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: I really don't understand why so many people are so desperate to defend the indefensible. So far as I'm concerned it's screamingly obvious that ***hotdog lawyer*** is a copying error / eggcorn. Look at [this NGram...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hot+dog+lawyer%2Chot-dog+lawyer%2Chotdog+lawyer%2Chot+shot+lawyer%2Chot-shot+lawyer%2Chotshot+lawyer&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chot%20shot%20lawyer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chot%20-%20shot%20lawyer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chotshot%20lawyer%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ...which at least manages to chart all variants of ***hotshot***, whilst flagging up  ***Ngrams not found: hot dog lawyer, hot-dog lawyer, hotdog lawyer***.

Comment: from what I read, in those links, it appears that hot dog lawyer was fairly derogatory, a Mac Donald's version of your high-class hotshot lawyer. Their meanings were not, and probably still aren't, identical. You can use all the bold in the world to state your case, I suspect that hot dog lawyer/attorney did not begin life as an acorn, but I'm not an American and I'm only basing my opinion on those examples I have found online.

Comment: Admittedly, it appears that the number of instances is very limited.

Answer (score 12):

The term [hotdogger](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hotdogger) is often used to describe anyone who is conceited, cocksure or arrogant.

Answer (score 5):

While not familiar with the term hot dog lawyer, growing up in Iowa the term “hot dog” as a description was used often by the older generations (I was born in 1978). It was used primarily as a term for a “show off”. One might “hot dog” it for the camera the way one “hams it up” for the camera. It was often used to describe athletes whose brashness, arrogance, vanity, or ego would outshine their performance, such as a out of control basketball player trying to show off elite level moves and turning the ball over as often as scoring. A hot shot would describe an elite level player whose performance would outshine their ego, such as a basketball player who consistently performs elite moves without trying to draw excessive attention to one self. It was also used to describe someone who is “full of crap”.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers here have noted, *hot-dog* as an adjective in the context of the quoted comment means "show-off" or "grandstanding" or "attention-seeking."

---

As for when that slang sense of the term originated, J.E. Lighter, *The Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1997) finds an astonishingly early instance, from 1894:

> **hot dog** *n.* **1.** Orig. *Stu[dent slang]* a cocky and proficient individual, now usu. a competitive athlete; (*also*) one who behaves, performs, or dresses in a flashy, conceited or ostentatious manner; a mere show-off.
>
> [First four cited occurrences:] 1894 in *Comments of Ety[mology]* (Nov. 1995) 19: Two Greeks a "hot dog" freshman sought./The Clothes they found, their favor bought. 1897 in *Comments of Ety.* (Nov. 1995) 18: "Brown's a hot dog, isn't he?" "Yes, he has so many pants." 1899 Kountz Baxter's Letters 34: A Messe de Mariage seems to be some kind of a wedding march, and a bishop, who is a real hot dog won't issue a certificate unless the band plays the Messe. 1900 *D[ialect] N[otes]* II 42: {College slang:} *hot dog*...One very proficient at certain things....A conceited person.

The "Brown's a hot dog" quotation comes from [*Wrinkle*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DxfiAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA13-PA7&dq=%22Brown%27s+a+hot+dog+isn%27t+he?%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirupvgxJPbAhUIl1QKHUXOCmAQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22Brown%27s%20a%20hot%20dog%20isn%27t%20he%3F%22&f=false) (June 19, 1897), a student publication of the University of Michigan; unfortunately the reference appears in *Punch*-style isolation as a two-line dialogue joke. The 1894 instance of "Two Greeks a "hot-dog" freshman sought" is supposedly also from an earlier volume of *Wrinkle*, although I haven't been able to find that volume online.

The *Dialect Notes* reference is to E.H. Babbitt, [*College Words and Phrases*](https://books.google.com/books?id=uZVBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22hot-dog+n.+1.+One+very+proficient%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5t57Gt5PbAhWohlQKHfkZAJgQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22hot-dog%20n.%201.%20One%20very%20proficient%22&f=false) (1900), which provides four definitions for *hot-dog*:

> **hot-dog,** *n.* 1. One very proficient at certain things. 2. A hot sausage. 3. A hard student. 4. A conceited person.

However, just four years earlier, Willard C. Gore, "[Student Slang](https://books.google.com/books?id=BtvhAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA148&dq=%22hot-dog+good+superior%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyquqHupPbAhXMlFQKHeOVCvMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22hot-dog%20good%20superior%22&f=false)" in *The Inlander* (January 1896) notes *hot-dog* as an entirely positive term (used as an adjective):

> **hot-dog.** Good, superior. "He has made some hot dog drawings for ——."

According to Lighter, *hot dog* in the sense of "frankfurter" also goes back to 1895,but he doesn't see it as the source of *hot dog* in the "show-off" sense. *Hot dog* as "frankfurter" has antecedents going back to the 1840s in the form of the word *dog* scurrilously associated with "sausage" (as an ingredient). In this regard, Lighter cites D. Corcoran, "[A Tourist in Trouble](https://books.google.com/books?id=z7GJL9M6P9gC&pg=RA2-PA152&dq=%22retails+the+latter,+tails+and+all,+as+sassenger+meat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWguzqvpPbAhUJB3wKHba5DU0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22retails%20the%20latter%2C%20tails%20and%20all%2C%20as%20sassenger%20meat%22&f=false)," in *Pickings from the Portfolio of the Reporter of the New Orleans "Picayune"* 152 (1846):

> "MEM.—New Orleans is a wery wile, wicious place : they kills men there with Bowie-knives and dogs with pisoned sassengers. They berries the former holesale in the swamp, and retails the latter, tails and all, as sassenger meat. It's a 'orrible state of society!"

And to like effect, Richard Jackson, "[Dutch Warbler](https://books.google.com/books?id=DDUJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22mit+dog%22+%22Popular+Songs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk8e_QwZPbAhULslQKHV8jA4YQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22mit%20dog%22%20%22Popular%20Songs%22&f=false)," in *Popular Songs* (originally 1864), to the tune of "oh where oh where has my little dog gone?":

> Un sasage ish goot, bolonie of course, Oh where oh where can he be?/ Dey makes um mit dog und dey makes em mit horse, I guess dey makes em mit he."

Leading finally to Farmer & Henley, [*Slang and Its Analogues Past and Present*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QLATAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA303&dq=%22Dogs,+subs.+(university)%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifm7OQxJPbAhUFkVQKHVkOCeMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Dogs%2C%20subs.%20(university)%22&f=false), volume 2 (1890–1891):

> **Dogs,** subs. (university).—**1.** Sausages; otherwise BAGS OF MYSTERY (*q.v.*), or CHAMBERS OF HORRORS, (*q.v.*).

So *hot-dog* as "show-off" is almost as old as *hot-dog* as "frankfurter," and it may have an independent origin. In fact, Dave Wilton, in a February 15, 2009, [posting on Word Origins](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/more/355/) suggests that the flashy sense of *hot-dog* derived from the idiom "putting on the dog":

> This usage is probably a variation on the older expression *putting on the dog*. From Lyman H. Bagg’s 1871 [*Four Years At Yale*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lsFJAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Four+Years+at+Yale%22+Bagg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv26qOyZPbAhUoh1QKHYDbB6oQ6AEIKTAA#v=snippet&q=%22put%20on%20dog%22&f=false):
>
> > *Dog*, style, splurge. To *put on dog*, is to make a flashy display, to cut a swell.
>
> It quickly moved from this sense of suave sartorial splendor to proficient, accomplished and eventually to its modern association with extreme sports and risky action.