# Where does the name "Hot-dog" come from?

Tags: etymology

I am curious: where does the name "Hot-dog" come from? I was thinking about the food.

Comment: Are you asking about the name of the food, or about the adjective applied to people who are showing off - "He is a good skier, but he's a bit of a hot-dog and tries to show off to impress girls"

Comment: My answer would just paraphrase [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_dog). Under 'etymology' the suggestion is that it's related to where people suspected the meat might come from (and sometimes they guessed right).

Comment: @JohnFeltz I was thinknig about the food

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Exchange expects questions to demonstrate some initial effort at research. A simple web search, for example, should turn up reputable sources like this [2016 *Smithsonian* magazine article](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/origins-coney-island-hot-dog-uniquely-american-story-180959659/). If these are inadequate in some way, you should [edit] your post to explain why.

Comment: @choster - That article doesn't explain the origin of the name.

Comment: [NHDSC then](http://www.hot-dog.org/culture/hot-dog-history). The point is that the OP should still describe research even if it has been fruitless. The origin of the term *hot dog* is in considerable dispute.

Comment: Related: [What does the term “hot dog lawyer” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446351/what-does-the-term-hot-dog-lawyer-mean)

Comment: Post your findings/research in your question  otherwise your question may be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hot dog (n.)** [entymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hot%20dog#etymonline_v_14494)

also hotdog, "sausage on a split roll," c. 1890, American English, from hot (adj.) + dog (n.). Many early references are in college student publications; later popularized, but probably not coined, by cartoonist T.A. "Tad" Dorgan (1877-1929). It is said in early explanations to echo a suspicion (occasionally justified) that sausages contained **dog meat**.